# Integration test rendering process - EmberJS

Tags: ember.js, npm, ember-qunit, es6-modules

I'm writing an integration test for one of my addon components. I've also linked it to a sibling project using [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link):

```
.. projects/
.... my-project/
.... my-linked-project/
```

I use one of the `my-linked-project` mixins in the `my-project` component in question.

```
//my-project/addon/components/my-component/component.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import ExternalMixin from 'my-linked-project/mixins/foo'

export default Ember.Component.extend(ExternalMixin, {
    ...
}
```

This runs fine with the application running, but seems to hit some issues when I `render` it in my integration test.

```
//my-project/tests/integration/components/my-component-test.js
import { moduleForComponent, test } from 'ember-qunit';
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';

moduleForComponent('my-component', 'Integration description', {
    integration: true
}

test('should render', function() {
    this.render(hbs`{{my-component}}`);
}
```

However I get `Error: Could not find module 'my-linked-project/mixins/foo'`.

1. Where can I read more about what happens when `render` / `hbs` are called?
2. Could the issue be the location of the test file, which can't find the external linked project?

Comment: Where do you put your foo.js ?

Answer (score 0):

It's worth removing the `npm link` from tech equation temporarily to see if that's causing your problems. What you have there looks fine ...